# "Copy Data Path" grayed out : what does it imply?

Tags: python, interface

On some elements of the interface, Copy Data Path is grayed out.
Does this mean that:

1. this element can't be accessed from python in any way whatsoever
2. it only can't be accessed from python through this particular interface area you clicked on but can be in another way
3. it can be accessed but was just not documented in the tooltip
4. other reason

Knowing what it means could save me a lot of potentially useless research in the future.

Comment: I would suggest you turn on python tooltips in blender preferences and use the hotkey Ctrl+Alt+Shift+C to copy the path for that object in python

Comment: @ViplavPrakash thanks but I did this and in the case of this cursor property, the python tooltip is not of much help